# Populating cells based off information in adjacent cells using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a sheet that is exported from an online system.

I have already worked out within VBA to reformat the entire sheet now I am left with my final part that has stumped me.

1. Column B is populated with 78 possible serial numbers (6 digits long). These serial numbers relate to any one of 10 specific machine names. Think of this like Vin numbers to a car.
2. What I would like to do in VBA is populate column A with the machine name based off the serial number listed in B.
3. The machine name is not listed anywhere on the sheet, I was hoping to have that information stored within the formula in VBA.

Below is an example of the data I am working with.

[image: Example Data]

I created a Vlookup formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B, {"161252","Machine 1";*Additional serial numbers and machine names*},2,0),"")
```

that when I record a macro and paste the formula in column A it works but when running that same macro on a new export only returns errors within VBA.

Comment: *Need VBA help* is clear because you posted here and used a VBA tag. *Been searching for days* is a meaningless statement that doesn't belong in your title. If you remove both of them, your title is blank. First, [edit] your question to remove the useless noise you've posted and replace it with something that describes the actual problem or question - it should be clear enough to be of use to someone seeing it in a search result. Second, this is a *question and answer* site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural. This is not a *here's my list of questions* site.

Comment: @KenWhite, you're on a roll ;)

Comment: Third, this is not a code writing service. Saying *I've done nothing but I've searched for days* is like saying *Honest, Teacher! I did my homework, but  my dog ate it. Please believe me!*. See [ask]. Then do a Google search for *VLookup*.

Comment: @CallumDA: You didn't wait until I finished. :-)

Comment: you are all probably correct and I apologize for not understanding how all of this works. It probably stems from the fact that I am in the military and obviously have a lower IQ than you all. VLookUp, I have watched countless videos on the topic. I created a formula using it that works, just not in VBA, not sure why but it works when I apply the formula to the cells when creating a macro but when I try and run the macro I get an error. Anyway sorry for wasting your time, I did the best I could in asking for help to try and better myself. I will go back to grunting and trigger pulling instead.

Comment: I will go ahead and delete this post and go back to searching online trying to understand how to incorporate VLookup in VBA. I was just trying to create a sheet to excel at what I do and stand out. "code writing service"? did you not see where I said I have already completed most of this project it is just one last step I am confused on? Sorry for the rant I just get so irritated when I just ask for help and get this back. Semper Fi

Comment: @SigSauer, don't delete your post. We can help but you just need to make a few edits first. 1. Include your code, 2. show us what you've tried, 3. Update your title to something more meaningful and a few of the other things that Ken White suggested

Comment: What reason do you have to *not* put the legend somewhere in the workbook? It could be e.g. on a hidden sheet.

Comment: @CallumDA Thank you for the willingness to help. I will be glad to edit anything I need to but I do not speak the language. Please let me know how I can reword this and I will do so asap.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have thought of that. The only reason why I did not go that route in the first place is because the sheet is exported from an online system. What I am trying to do is write script that will reformat the jumbeled information exported into a easy to comprehend set of data. I was trying to have the information within VBA so that I did not have to have another sheet with the legend stored and copy and paste it each time I export this information.

Comment: Read these : Fomula through VBA : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx, Vlookup : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1, Paste as value :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx, HiddenSheet :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197786.aspx

Comment: There is something that troubles me; your serial numbers in column B are left aligned. Unless you did this on purpose, they are text since text is (by default) left aligned). However, the serial numbers in column G (your legend) are right aligned (the way a true number  **should** be). With VLOOKUP (and other functions) you cannot locate a true number by supplying text-that-look-like-a-number. So even if you get your VLOOKUP formula correct, it may not return any matching machine name.

Comment: @Jeeped that was a quick example of the information that I am working with. I just copied and pasted into another sheet to provide a visual. But you are correct, I spent 2 days trying to understand why I was having issues with Vlookup only to learn about the text vs number issue and having to figure out how to over come that.

Comment: Instead of using `=VLOOKUP(VALUE(B2), ...` you can grab all of column B and use Data, Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Finish and the entire column should covert to true numbers. In VBA it is a one liner (record yourself doing it).

Answer (score 1):

You could store the legend in a dictionary.

In a standard code module put this code (properly fleshed out):

```
Public Legend As Object
Public Initialized As Boolean

Sub InitializeLegend()
    Initialized = True
    Set Legend = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Legend.Add 160743, "Machine 1"
    Legend.Add 160804, "Machine 2"
    'etc.
    'etc.
    Legend.Add 165284, "Machine 1"
End Sub

Function Machine(SerialNumber As Variant) As String
    If Not Initialized Then InitializeLegend
    Machine = Legend(SerialNumber)
End Function
```

Then `Machine()` can be used directly in the spreadsheet.

If you are new to VBA, it is hard to exaggerate just how useful dictionaries can be. Here is a nice introduction: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: Thank you Sir. I am processing all the information you posted and reading the link you provided. I will let you know what I have learned from this and how it is working on my end.

Comment: I thought my head hurt before haha. I have been able to create the dictionary while I am not totally sure why you used "legend" but I am sure that it is not something I need to spend to much time on at this point. Now I am trying to move on to how to reference this dictionary to auto fill column A with the machine name based on the key in column B.

Comment: @SigSauer In your question you referred to it as a "Legend", so I chose that as a variable name. You can obviously pick some other word if you want. You do need to be careful that the type of the data matches the type of the key. If it is an issue, you could experiment with replacing the line `Machine = Legend(SerialNumber)` with `Machine = Legend(Val(SerialNumber))`

Comment: Thank you for the background information I was just curious as to the use of legend and that helps a lot. I am reading additional sites now trying to figure out how to auto fill based of this dictionary in column A. But first I will need coffee for this venture!